# Populate results of one-to-many in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: `activity` and `tag`. One `activity` have many `tags`. I need to optimize our current setup, where we find all activities inside the table and then iterate over each activity to find all tags. Finally we dispose the content as JSON.

Here is an example:

```
-- Query that we execute one time
SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `activity`

-- Query that we execute N times
SELECT `id`, `name`, `color`
FROM `tag`
WHERE `tag`.`activityId` = $activityId
```

So our final code looks something like that:

```
$result = mysqli_query("
    SELECT `id`, `name`
    FROM `activity`
");

$data = array();

for ($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $data[$i]["activityId"] = $row["id"];
    $data[$i]["name"] = $row["name"];
    $data[$i]["tags"] = array();

    $activityId = $row["id"];

    $resultTags = mysqli_query("
        SELECT `id`, `name`, `color`
        FROM `tag`
        WHERE `tag`.`activityId` = $activityId
    ");

    for ($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_rows($resultTags); $j++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTags);

        $data[$i]["tags"][$j]["name"] = $row["name"];
        $data[$i]["tags"][$j]["color"] = $row["color"];
    }
}
```

PS: this is a pseudo-code, our queries and tables are way more complex, but that's basically the essence of our problem.

Is it possible to accomplish that using inner queries, or even better, just with joins?

Since we need to populate around 5 tables, we end up executing 5 queries for each activity we have.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure just `JOIN` the **tag** table on the **activity** table.

Your query should look something like this.

```
SELECT activity.id, activity.name, tag.name AS tagName, tag.color AS tagColor
FROM activity
JOIN tag ON tag.activityId = activity.id;
```

The idea that the activity table's primary key is `id` and that each row is unique (i.e. the name will never change for any given `activity.id`), then the JOIN is safe even if the there are no tags. We'll get back at least `N` rows where `N` is the number of `tag.activityId` rows that have a corresponding `id` in `activity`.

So in PHP you can build the array with a single query like this.

```
$data = [];
foreach($result as $row) {

    $tags = ["name" => $row["tagName"], "color" => $row["tagColor"]];

    if (isset($data[$row["id"]])) {
        $data[$row["id"]]["tags"][] = $tags; 
    } else {
        $data[$row["id"]] = [
            [
                "id"   => $row["id"],
                "name" => $row["name"],
                "tags" => [$tags],
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

Because the information in the activity table will never change, then the only thing we need to append is the tags, which we do by checking `isset($data[$row["id"]])` inside the loop.

So from this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66d51/1) you can see a working example of the two tables where we have 4 rows in the `activity`, and 6 rows in the `tag` table. This gives us a total of 6 rows. Since one of the ids in the activity table doesn't have any tags it's excluded from the result set. To get back rows with 0 tags you can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66d51/2).

```
SELECT activity.id, activity.name,
       tag.activityId AS tagId, tag.name AS tagName, tag.color AS tagColor
FROM activity
LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.activityId = activity.id;
```

Which means we get null values for empty tag rows. So we can modify the PHP to look like this.

```
$data = [];
foreach($result as $row) {

    $tags = empty($row["tagId"]) ?: ["name" => $row["tagName"], "color" => $row["tagColor"]];

    if (isset($data[$row["id"]]) && $tags) {
        $data[$row["id"]]["tags"][] = $tags; 
    } else {
        $data[$row["id"]] = [
            [
                "id"   => $row["id"],
                "name" => $row["name"],
                "tags" => $tags ? [$tags] : [],
            ],
        ];
    }

}
```

So your finally output from PHP using `json_encode`, with the sample data in the SQLFiddle, should look something like this.

```
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tagName": "tag-a",
                "tagColor": "red"
            },
            {
                "tagName": "tag-b",
                "tagColor": "green"
            },
            {
                "tagName": "tag-c",
                "tagColor": "blue"
            }
        ]
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bar",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tagName": "tag-a",
                "tagColor": "orange"
            },
            {
                "tagName": "tag-b",
                "tagColor": "red"
            }
        ]
    },
    "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "baz",
        "tags": [
            {
                "tagName": "tag-a",
                "tagColor": "purple"
            }
        ]
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "quix",
        "tags": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sherif, but I forgot to mention that I need to `group` the table by `activity.id`, since I'm joining several other tables. In this case, it won't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work, exactly? If `activity.id` is a PK then that should have no effect on this use case.

Comment: Include the dubious `GROUP BY` clause and schema in which you claim it wouldn't work and I'd be happy to show you how to get it to work.

Comment: @Serif For example, I have a `material` table and I need to know how many materials I have for that single `activity`, so in my selectors, I place a `COUNT(material.activityId)`. So that works, I need a group by mechanism.

Comment: Well, `SELECT COUNT(materiali.activityId)` doesn't roll up. So, I can't really address your question any more elaborately without seeing the schema and the expected result.